# Prove $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to some $f(x)$ but the convergence is not uniform

Tags: uniform-convergence

**EDIT**: Given $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{(x^2+1)x}{1+(n+1)^{2}x^{2}}$

Show that $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to some $f(x)$ but that the convergence is not uniform.

**EDIT**: I tried finding $\varepsilon$ and $x$ so that $\forall$ $n_0\in\Bbb{N}$ $\exists$ $n$$\ge$$n_0$ $\exists$ $x$$\in$$\Bbb{R}$ so that $\mid$$f_n(x)-f(x)$$\mid$$\ge$$\varepsilon$. 
But I could not do that. Am I on the right track? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Uniform convergence is a property not just of the sequence, but also the domain. What is $X$?

Comment: Hint: have a look at the definition fo the uniform convergence. What you wrote is slightly off to show that this does not hold. However, by studying $1+(n+1)^2x$ might be a good idea... on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: $X$ cannot be a generic metric space, because its elements appear in algebraic formulae in the definition of $f_n$, so I guess $X \subset \Bbb C$ or, most probably, $X \subset \Bbb R$. As @UmbertoP. also stated, uniform convergence depends not only on your functions, but also on your domain (a sequence might converge uniformly on some domain and not on some other one). Therefore, until you tell us who $X$ is, we shall not be able to help  you.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

For $x>1$, we have

$$\left|\frac{(1+x^2)x^2}{1+(n+1)^2x}\right|>\frac{(1+x^2)x}{x^2+(1+n)^2x^2}=\frac{(1+x^2)/x}{1+(1+n)^2}>\frac{x}{1+(1+n^2)} \tag 1$$

Can you find  a number $\epsilon >0$ and some value of $x \in [1,\infty)$ such that $\epsilon$ is smaller than the right-hand side of $(1)$ for all $n\ge 1$?

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake the actual sequence is $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{(x^2+1)x}{1+(n+1)^{2}x^{2}}$  @Dr. MV

Comment: @Lucila25 That's OK.  I edited accordingly.